# Android Studio 3.5 run application on several devices

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have several devices connected to Android Studio 3.5.
To run on all devices I need to make monkey job and all time click "Run on several device" and all time select devices one by one.

Is any solution to store selected devices to start from one button as it was in Android Studio 3.4?

Comment: This issue has been created on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140056248)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android studio 4.0 ***Run on Multiple Devices*** save selection between launch

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I too faced the same problem. But I got the solution.
You can Install a Plugin from the Marketplace - Android Studio.
***Android Run On Multiple Devices***. After installation, connect all the devices you wanted to run the app. Then use ***CTRL+SHIFT+F10*** then ***ENTER.*** it will run the app in all the devices you have connected to.

[image]